# Angular 2 Herouku deployment crashes

Tags: angular, heroku

I am tried of thinking what is going wrong when deploying angular app on herouku.

My current directory looks like this

`node_modules`
`src`
`package.json`

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:upgrade": "tsc",
    "serve:upgrade": "http-server",
    "build:aot": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json && rollup -c rollup-config.js",
    "serve:aot": "lite-server -c bs-config.aot.json",
    "build:babel": "babel src -d src --extensions \".es6\" --source-maps",
    "copy-dist-files": "node ./copy-dist-files.js",
    "i18n": "ng-xi18n",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/tsc-wrapped": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~4.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4",
    "ap-angular2-fullcalendar": "1.1.0",
    "appearin-sdk": "0.0.4",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/angular": "^1.5.16",
    "@types/angular-animate": "^1.5.5",
    "@types/angular-cookies": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/angular-mocks": "^1.5.5",
    "@types/angular-resource": "^1.5.6",
    "@types/angular-route": "^1.3.2",
    "@types/angular-sanitize": "^1.3.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "babel-cli": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-angular2": "^0.0.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine": "~2.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rollup": "^0.41.6",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^8.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "source-map-explorer": "^1.3.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

[image: This is the log error i am getting]

Comment: Hi..Remove all scripts from package.json file. If you have a server then add mainserver js file in the script else leave it blank for more details look my angular application in github [link](https://github.com/thangavel28/sim/blob/master/package.json)

Comment: I removed all scripts still same error.

Comment: still.. same error or different error

Comment: you installed all necessary packages? both globally and locally. check if you have setup environmental variables

Comment: yes @Aravind installed all the packages..

Comment: setup environmental variables as in?